# Multiple sites in multiple projects on the same rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've searched the web, but I can only find information on sharing code between multiple sites and on separating the database to isolated models. This is not what I want.

I want to run a single rails server, with a single DNS address and a single port - `http://myportal.com` - that will handle several other sites - `http://myportal.com/site1`, `http://myportal.com/site2` etc.

I want each site to have it's own folder(and SCM repository), it's own database, it's own routing - it's own *everything*. That is - I want to be able to develop each site as a standalone - that means I need to be able to run site1 site as `http://localhost:3000` and not `http://localhost:3000/site1`.

On the server, the root site(the one that responds to the `http://myportal.com` address should be the one I run the server from, and it should know the absolute paths of the other sites(which will be in different directories on the server, not in child directories of the root site) and provide routing information for them - but it should also chain to the other sites `routes.rb` files. That means that if I go to address `http://myportal.com/site1/books/` the root site should handle `http://myportal.com/site1`, and site1 should handle `/books/`. The root site should not need to know about the other sites' internal routing structures.

Is this possible? Right now I'm running the rails server that comes with the gem(`rails server` from the command line) on a Windows Server 2008 server, but I'm willing to install another server if that's what needed to accomplish the goal I described.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with Apache or nginx and possibly IIS if configured correctly. I'm most familiar with Apache and the flexible [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) components that can facilitate this.

The idea is you rewrite `http://example.com/` to be `http://example.com:3000/` and `http://example.com/site2` as `http://example.com:3001/site2` and so forth.

It's also possible to do this with Passenger and some clever use of the `VirtualHost` directive, but you may have to fiddle to get a configuration that works for you. Remember that rewriting the headers to route internally has no effect on the resulting HTML your servers emit.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I need to use multiple ports, and to do the routing work in the DNS? Is there no way to do this with a single port?

Comment: DNS directs clients to your server. Your server needs to internally route requests to the appropriate port. This is perhaps the easiest way to break out multiple sites because the `VirtualHost` directive captures anything with a specific host name by default, but only on a specific port. Using multiple host + port combinations gives you the flexibility you want.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try. Got any decent tutorials about `VirtualHost` in rails?

Comment: There has to be a billion of them out there, though the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/) has most of what you need. If that doesn't help, try posting a specific question. The key is declaring `Listen 3001` and having a section like `<VirtualHost *:3001>` to define where to serve that content.

Answer (score 0):

Create a symlink:

```
cd ~/Sites
ln -s /Users/hg/Developer/Rails/railsproj1/public ./railsproj1
```

modify apache config file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot /Users/hg/Sites
  <Directory /Users/hg/Sites>
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
  RailsBaseURI /railsproj1
  RailsEnv development
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer source: http://collab.stat.ucla.edu/users/jose/weblog/9e335/

Comment: more source: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri

Comment: That's what I would have done - if I didn't have to run in on a Windows machine...